# iOS - checking ping

Tags: ios, ping

I need to check what is the best server for a user, by ping, to choose the player the best server so he won't be slow, it's really important. What would be the best way to check this out on iOS?

Comment: The app is multiplayer game, I have 2 servers, I want to check the ping of each server to choose him a server.